# How to check the availability of a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I have to run a set of code related to worksheet "**wins**", but only if that worksheet exist.

Please share a code to check the availability of sheet "wins". If worksheet "wins" exist, then only I want to run that set of code, else I want to skip executing that set of code and move to next line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `On Error Resume Next` to skip the errror which occurs if you try access a not existing worksheet and assigning it to a object variable. So if the worksheet does not exist, no error occurs but the variable is `Nothing`. If the worksheet exists, then the variable is not `Nothing`.

Example:

```
Sub test()

 Dim wsWins As Worksheet

 On Error Resume Next
 Set wsWins = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("wins")
 On Error GoTo 0

 If Not wsWins Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "Worksheet wins exists."
 Else
  MsgBox "Worksheet wins does not exist."
 End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Axel's answer will work nicely. Some people prefer not to use error throwing to test if something exists. If you're one of them then I use the following quite a lot in a Utility module. It'll work for Worksheets, Charts, etc. (basically anything that's a collection with a 'Name' property):

```
Public Function ExcelObjectExists(testName As String, excelCollection As Object) As Boolean
    Dim item As Object

    On Error GoTo InvalidObject

    For Each item In excelCollection
        If item.Name = testName Then
            ExcelObjectExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    ExcelObjectExists = False
    Exit Function

InvalidObject:
    MsgBox "Developer error: invalid collection object passed in ExcelObjectExists."
    ExcelObjectExists = False

End Function
```

You can call it like this:

```
    If ExcelObjectExists("wins", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets) Then
```